# Adaptation of the merge clauses in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, merge

I have a code which is up and running but the problem that I have is that it includes a lot of MERGE clauses as it was intended to be run from SQL Server 2008 and forward. But the problem is that a new customer is running SQL Server 2005 and as you know the Merge clause is not available till SQL Server 2008, so my question is if there is not a way to parse the this clauses automatically or if there is another solution (apart from rewriting all the clauses in clasical clauses ) as the customer is not willing to upgrade the DB.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am not aware of any sql merge converters.

But realistically, after you have converted a few manually you will quickly be able to convert the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you will need to re-write all of your `MERGE` clauses for SQL Server 2005.

You can use the 2005 friendly `output` clause to achieve the same functionality but with more verbose SQL. This approach will also work on SQL Server 2008.

http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql.html

Comment: Correct. I would spend the time to rewrite the MERGE with UPDATE/INSERT statements. The client has to consider the cost of upgrading the server vs downgrading the code. Hours to downgrade X hourly rate (including QA) versus cost of upgrade. Consider the performance improvements and the fact that this type of gymnastic would not be necessary in the future. He is now two versions behind, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could put together a C# (or whatever) app to parse the merge statements and create insert/update statements from them.  I mean, that's a horrible idea, but you *can* do it...

You'd have to pull out the "ON" part, add it to a check IF EXISTS and the update part, then add the column list to the insert part.  You could even programmatically (sic?) create SP params and everything.

Heh.  Good luck.